# getting error while writing data onto cloud bigTable through dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-bigtable

I am using 2nd gen cloud function to trigger dataflow job. Dataflow template is basically reading parquet files from cloud storage and loading data onto bigTable.
Here are the code and package details

```py
import os
import datetime
import logging
from configparser import ConfigParser
import apache_beam as beam
from google.cloud.bigtable import Client
from google.cloud.bigtable.row import DirectRow
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from google.cloud import bigtable
from google.cloud.bigtable import column_family
from google.cloud.bigtable import row_filters

from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigtableio import WriteToBigTable

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

config_object = ConfigParser()
config_object.read("config.ini")

project_id = config_object["uprn"]["project_id"]
instance_id = config_object["uprn"]["instance_id"]
table_id = config_object["uprn"]["table_id"]
column_family_id = config_object["uprn"]["column_family_id"]
#input_columns = config_object["uprn"]["input_columns"]
timestamp = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)
logging.info("--Starting..")

#client = bigtable.Client(project=project_id, admin=True)
#instance = client.instance(instance_id)
#table = instance.table(table_id)

def big_table_load(ele):
    try:
        rows = []
        column_names = list(ele.keys())
        row_key = str(str(ele['uprn'])).encode()
        logging.info("--row_key "+str(row_key))
        row = DirectRow(row_key)

        for key in column_names:
            row.set_cell(
                column_family_id, key, str(ele[key]).encode('utf-8'), timestamp=timestamp
            )
        rows.append(row)
        return rows
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info("Error encountered for row_key " + str(row_key) + " with error message "+ str(e))

def find_err_file():
    filename_err = user_options.efilename.get()
    return filename_err


class UserOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_value_provider_argument('--input_location',
                                           default='gs://my-proj-dev-local-landing-zone/mock_data/*'
                                           )


pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
user_options = pipeline_options.view_as(UserOptions)


def run():
    try:
        with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
            records = (p | 'Read' >> beam.io.ReadFromParquet(user_options.input_location)
                       | 'Format Rows' >> beam.ParDo(big_table_load)
                       | WriteToBigTable(
                        project_id=project_id,
                        instance_id=instance_id,
                        table_id=table_id
                    )
                       )
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info(e)
        raise e


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Requirement.txt

```
google-cloud-bigtable==1.7.0
apache-beam[gcp]==2.39.0
```

Error processing instruction process_bundle-4225915941562411087-3. Original traceback is Traceback (most recent call last): File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1232, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._invoke_bundle_method File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 475, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnInvoker.invoke_finish_bundle File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 481, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnInvoker.invoke_finish_bundle File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigtableio.py", line 187, in finish_bundle self.batcher.flush() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigtableio.py", line 88, in flush status.code))) Exception: Failed to write a batch of 12 records due to 'not_found' During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 267, in _execute response = task() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 340, in  lambda: self.create_worker().do_instruction(request), request) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 581, in do_instruction getattr(request, request_type), request.instruction_id) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 618, in process_bundle bundle_processor.process_bundle(instruction_id)) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 1001, in process_bundle op.finish() File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 736, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.finish File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 738, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.finish File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 739, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.finish File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1253, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.finish File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1234, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._invoke_bundle_method File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1281, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1232, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._invoke_bundle_method File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 475, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnInvoker.invoke_finish_bundle File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 481, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnInvoker.invoke_finish_bundle File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigtableio.py", line 187, in finish_bundle self.batcher.flush() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigtableio.py", line 88, in flush status.code))) Exception: Failed to write a batch of 12 records due to 'not_found' [while running 'WriteToBigTable/ParDo(_BigTableWriteFn)-ptransform-43']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a “not found” error - does the table and columns family you are writing to exist?

Comment: Thank you, Gary, for your take on this. Yes, I figured out that the column family I mentioned in the code was missing on the BigTable table. I fixed it, and this error got resolved.

Comment: Yes thanks @gary . Its due to missing column family name.